# CSS3-animation: Background-position with steps - image blinks

Tags: css, animation

I'm making a CSS3-animation of a desk with a blinking lamp using a spritesheet with only two different sprites. The problem is, that the animation when using percent instead from "from" and "to" causes the entire image to blink, even though the animation runs as it should.

It works fine when I use this:

```
background: url("../img/desk.svg");
background-size: auto 200%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
-webkit-animation: desk 5s steps(2) infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes {
   from {
      background-position: 0 0;
   }
   to {
      background-position: 0 200%;
   }
}
```

But when using this, the image blinks. The animaton itself works as it should though:

```
@-webkit-keyframes desk {
   0% {
       background-position: 0 0%;
   }
   10% {
       background-position: 0 200%;
   }
   15% {
       background-position: 0 0%;
   }
   20% {
       background-position: 0 200%;
   }
   25% {
       background-position: 0 0%;
   }
   100% {
       background-position: 0 200%;
   }
}
```

I am clueless to why this happens, as I'm using a spritesheet, and the image wont have to load every time.

Hope someone can help me out :)

Comment: You should post more code .

Anyway, I would try changing steps to 1 in your time function

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
background: url("../img/desk.svg");
background-size: auto 200%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 0 0;
-webkit-animation: desk 5s steps(2) infinite;

@-webkit-keyframes desk{
   from {
      background-position: 0 0;
   }
   to {
      background-position: 0 200%;
   }
}
```

Comment: Just to make it more clear. I'd like to achieve a non-consistent blink-effect. Hence using the percentage instead of the above.

Comment: it will be very helpful if u could show your could in codepen or jsfiddle,